# Solving spy, liar, and truthteller puzzle using propositional calculus

Tags: logic, puzzle

I watched a [recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e3RdC7VXv6s) from MindYourDecisions. One of its problems is:

> ALice, Bob, and Charlie are one of each type: a truth-teller (always tell a truth), a liar (always lies), and a spy (can lie or tell a truth). Alice says she is not a truth teller; Bob says he is not a spy; and Charlie says he is not a liar. What type is Charlie?

It reminds me of [Knight and Knaves puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240256/is-there-a-general-effective-method-to-solve-smullyan-style-knights-and-knaves-p). I wish to solve this problem symbolically.

I introduce three propositional variables: $A$, $B$, and $C$. $A$ represents "Alice is a truth-teller," $B$ represents "Bob is a truth-teller" and $C$ represents "Charlie is a truth-teller." I am not sure how to translate the problem statement into symbols. I think it would be:

$$A\longleftrightarrow\lnot A$$
$$B\longleftrightarrow\lnot (B\lor\lnot B)$$
$$C\longleftrightarrow\lnot C$$

They look contradictory... Any better ideas?

Comment: It should be clear from Alice's statement that she is a spy. That's because she can't be always lying (otherwise she's saying the truth on this occasion) and she can't be always saying the truth (otherwise she's lying on this occasion), so she must be a spy. Then Bob must be a truth teller and Charlie a liar. The symbolic formulation, particularly the statement $A \leftrightarrow \neg A$ tells you instantly about who can't be a consistent liar or a consistent truth teller on this occasion. (Someone else write an answer please)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not so straightforward to formalize this with propositional logic (But it's possible as @Bram28 answered). In your attemption, you made $A,B,C$ represents that Alice, Bob, Charlie is a truth-teller respectively while the problem is that whether  someone is a lair or a spy cannot simply expressed in terms of if they are a truth-teller or not. That Bob and Charlie's words cannot be expressed within this setting.

Let $A,B,C$ be the collection of all possible sentences said by Alice, Bob, Charlie respectively. Given that

> Alice, Bob, and Charlie are one of each type: a truth-teller (always tell a truth), a liar (always lies), and a spy (can lie or tell a truth).

\begin{align*}
(\forall \varphi\in S,\varphi)\lor(\forall\varphi\in S,\lnot\varphi)\lor(\exists\varphi\in S,\varphi\land\exists\varphi\in S,\lnot \varphi)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

where $S=A,B$ or $C$.

Alice: $\color{blue}{\lnot(\forall \varphi\in A,\varphi)}$ (I'm not a truth-teller.)

Bob: $\lnot(\exists\varphi\in B,\varphi\land\exists\varphi\in B,\lnot\varphi)$ (I'm not a spy.)

Charlie: $\lnot(\forall \varphi\in C,\lnot \varphi)$ (I'm not a lair.)

1. Suppose Alice is a lair i.e. $\forall\varphi\in A,\lnot \varphi$ that anything said by Alice must be false gives
   \begin{align*}
   \lnot\color{blue}{\lnot(\forall \varphi\in A,\varphi)}\equiv\forall\varphi\in A,\varphi
   \end{align*}
   However, that says Alice is a truth-teller, a contradiction. Alice is not a lair.
2. Suppose Alice is a truth-teller i.e. $\forall\varphi\in A,\varphi$ that anything said by Alice must be true gives
   $$\color{blue}{\lnot(\forall \varphi\in A,\varphi)}$$
   However, that says Alice is not a truth-teller, a contradiction. Alice is not a truth-teller.

By $(1)$ have $\exists\varphi\in A,\varphi\land \exists\varphi\in A,\lnot \varphi$ that Alice is a spy. Follows Bob is a truth-teller and Charlie is a lair.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with propositional logic ... but it's not as straightforward as with the Knight and Knaves puzzles.

OK, so let's define a bunch of atomic statements:

$A_T$: Alice is a truth-teller

$A_S$: Alice is a spy

$A_L$: Alice is a liar

$B_T$: Bob is a truth-teller

$B_S$: Bob is a spy

$B_L$: Bob is a liar

$C_T$: Charlie is a truth-teller

$C_S$: Charlie is a spy

$C_L$: Charlie is a liar

Now, Alice is either a truth-teller, spy, or liar, so we have all of the following statements:

1. $A_T \leftrightarrow (\neg A_S \land \neg A_L)$
2. $A_S \leftrightarrow (\neg A_T \land \neg A_L)$
3. $A_L \leftrightarrow (\neg A_S \land \neg A_T)$

Same with Bob and Charlie:

4. $B_T \leftrightarrow (\neg B_S \land \neg B_L)$
5. $B_S \leftrightarrow (\neg B_T \land \neg B_L)$
6. $B_L \leftrightarrow (\neg B_S \land \neg B_T)$
7. $C_T \leftrightarrow (\neg C_S \land \neg C_L)$
8. $C_S \leftrightarrow (\neg C_T \land \neg C_L)$
9. $C_L \leftrightarrow (\neg C_S \land \neg C_T)$

Also, when it says: "Alice, Bob, and Charlie are one of each type" I assume they mean that there is 1 truth-teller, 1 spy, and 1 liar between them. So, we can also add:

10. $A_T \leftrightarrow (\neg B_T \land \neg C_T)$
11. $A_S \leftrightarrow (\neg B_S \land \neg C_S)$
12. $A_L \leftrightarrow (\neg B_L \land \neg C_L)$
13. $B_T \leftrightarrow (\neg A_T \land \neg C_T)$
14. $B_S \leftrightarrow (\neg A_S \land \neg C_S)$
15. $B_L \leftrightarrow (\neg A_L \land \neg C_L)$
16. $C_T \leftrightarrow (\neg A_T \land \neg B_T)$
17. $C_S \leftrightarrow (\neg A_S \land \neg B_S)$
18. $C_L \leftrightarrow (\neg A_L \land \neg B_L)$

OK, now for the statements they give. Alice says "I am not a truth-teller"

This means that the statement is true if Alice is a truth teller, and the statement is false if Alice is a liar:

19. $A_T \to \neg A_T$
20. $A_L \to A_T$

Bob says: "I am not a spy" becomes:

21. $B_T \to \neg B_S$
22. $B_L \to B_S$

Charlie: "I am not a liar":

23. $C_T \to \neg C_L$
24. $C_L \to C_L$

OK, so now let's infer (I'll use a mix of fairly standard inference and equivalence rules)

25. $\neg A_T \lor \neg A_T$ (Implication 19)
26. $\neg A_T$ (Idempotence 25)
27. $\neg A_L$ (Modus Tollens 20,26)
28. $\neg A_T \land \neg A_L$ ($\land$ Intro 26,27)
29. $A_S$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim  2,28)
30. $\neg B_S \land \neg C_S$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim  11,29)
31. $\neg B_S$ ($\land$ Elim, 30)
32. $\neg B_L$ (Modus Tollens, 22,31)
33. $\neg B_S \land \neg B_L$ ($\land$ Intro 31,32)
34. $B_T$ (\leftrightarrow Elim  4,33)
35. $\neg A_T \land \neg C_T$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim  13,34)
36. $\neg C_S$ ($\land$ Elim 30)
37. $\neg C_T$ ($\land$ Elim 35)
38. $\neg C_S \land \neg C_T$ ($\land$ Intro 36,37)
39. $C_L$ ($\leftrightarrow$ Elim  9,38)