# Prove $\vdash(A\supset B)\supset C\equiv C\overline{\vee }[A\wedge \neg(B\vee C)]$ using your favorite method

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I've been playing with Boolean logic vs ordinary laws of logic like DeMorgan's etc., and I've come up with the following theorem in about 4 lines: $$[(A\supset B)\supset C]\equiv \left\{C\overline{\vee }[A\wedge {\sim}(B\vee C)]\right\}$$ so I was wondering if there exists a simple proof in terms of ordinary logical laws. The $\overline{\vee}$ is an exclusive or. Pretty much, this is a question of the efficiency of one kind of way of dealing with propositional logic over another.

Comment: This is invalid, unless there is a typo. A counter-example is when $v(A)=1$, $v(B)=0$, and $v(C)=1$.

Comment: @PW_246 Fixed. $(A\supset B)\supset C$ is equivalent to $C\overline{\vee}[A\wedge {\sim}(B\vee C)]$

Comment: You should define what you mean by "simple proof." In this case, I'm guessing you mean a "a proof consisting of no more than $4$ lines?"

Comment: In some proof systems this is easier to prove than others, yes. Theoretically, a proof system could have this very statement as an instance of an axiom or inference rule, in which case you would have a 1 step proof. In other proof systems you might not be able to prove this in less than 100 lines. … Does that answer your question? Not sure what exactly you are asking.

Comment: @Bram28 Actually, this is less of an absolute "is it possible?" and more of a "give an example using your favorite pick." This is so that I, and everyone else, can practically see examples of the advantages/disadvantages of different systems. It's more to inspire creativity.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Hmmm, I remember I did a post some years ago where I proved the same thing using 7 or 8 different systems.  Let me see if I can find it. Are you only interested in derivational (step-by-step-inference) systems or would other methods of demonstrations be ok too? E.g.truth-tables can be used … though you wouldn’t really be able to count any ‘steps’ with a method like that.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Well, I can’t find that one post anymore, but here is a post I found that does have some interestingly different methods to prove a tautology like yours: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3622962/how-do-i-prove-this-statement-is-a-tautology-without-using-truth-tables In the Answers you will find the method of short (or indirect) truth-table, algebra, truth-tree, and a purely semantic method.  None of them are derivations.

Comment: @Bram28 I won't restrict my interests to step-by-step inference methods, because this is definitely a more creative/fun question. Truth trees are some of my favorite, but I would prefer a line-by-line computation. I think what I'm most interested in is to see a clever proof in the ordinary sense of assumptions, arrow-in, arrow-out, and-in, and-out, etc.. since I think it would be a challenge

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Would you still allow equivalence rules (so basically using boolean algebra equivalences) as part of the inference rules, or would you want to restrict to pure one-way inference rules? Also, very few inference systems have rules for the exclusive or …

Comment: @Bram28 Yes, for sure equivalences are allowed.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad Cool. And you say you proved this with equivalence rules in just 4 steps? I’d love to see that! Can you post that?

Comment: @Bram28 Yes. I just did field arithmetic over the field $\mathbb F_2$ and identified certain logical operations with their corresponding forms.

Comment: @AlexanderConrad I’d be interested to see what that looks like … can you add that to your post?